# Jar produced by Kotlin Multiplatform Library project not visible in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform

I have created minimal project based on official tutorial https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/mpp-create-lib.html

Gradle build produces .jar file which looks good (stream-api-lib-jvm-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar)

But when I include this jar (manually) into my Android Studio project, it cannot find the classes (Invalidating cache already tried).

[image: Jar content]

Gradle config changes for adding the lib (into app/libs)

```
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs') 
implementation files('libs/stream-api-lib-jvm-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar')
```

Comment: I think you'll need to show a lot more of your gradle config. If you're adding the jar manually vs in gradle, you probably have issues with module dependencies, etc. I haven't tried that in years, so won't be much help.

Comment: Added gralde changes. The most puzzling to me is that I supposed this should be kind of usual approach when using MPP library so I would expect it to work out of the box. And also adding a .jar was always straightforward, I have no idea which configuration setting can produce such effect.

Comment: I'm also waiting for a proper solution, I have a module in an Android project which contains both Java & Kotlin files & I made a jar file from that module but in the jar file only  Java classes files are present Kotlin files are not there in the jar file

Answer (score 0):

Finally found the reason: in my case kotlin file in library which I tried to access, did not have the "package" directive on top.